# String property not reflecting correct value in the UI when its value is 10

Tags: angular, typescript

I have written a property in typescript angular, that will basically return the actual value of min and max to the UI. So at the moment what I am trying to achieve is

For e.g.
case 1 - If min: 10 and max: 40 then display min as 10 and max as 40 in the UI
case 2 - If min: null and max: null then display unknown in the UI
case 3 - If min: 0 and max: 10 then  display min as 0 and max as 10 in the UI

Case 1 and 2 are working but case 3 is not working. It is showing both the min and max as 0. Could anybody tell what the problem is ?  min and max are string properties

```
public get cardNotPresentTurnover(): string {
    return !(
      this.location?.cardNotPresentTurnover?.min &&
      this.location?.cardNotPresentTurnover?.max
    )
      ? 'Unknown'
      : `${this.location.cardNotPresentTurnover.min}% - ${this.location.cardNotPresentTurnover.max}%`;
  }
```

Comment: Hi, could you please provide a reproduction of this not working? Say, in StackBlitz?

Comment: I think your problem is that you're using `&&` with `min` which is 0. 0 is falsy which means that `0 && 10` is the same as doing `false && 10` or `null && 10`. I would check for `null` and `undefined` instead of just using `&&`.

Comment: When min and max has some values ain't you getting  `UnKnown`?  How come first and second are working with the above code? Can you share more descriptive code snippet?

Comment: I am so sorry. I am getting the value as 0 and 10 percent in the UI when printing the values from the individual properties but getting unknown displayed in property cardNotPresentTurnover.

Comment: Your getter function looks fine, if I do something like that: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-rbfqqq?file=index.js (see console output) it works as expected. Without a full example it's hard to debug.

Answer (score 0):

When you're using the logical AND operator with `0` in JavaScript it will be treated as `false` because the value is [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy). Therefore, when you're comparing your third scenario, you're comparing `false` AND `10` which will always result in `false`.

Try to check the values for `undefined` and `null` instead:

```
export const isNil = (obj: any): obj is null | undefined =>
  typeof obj === 'undefined' || obj === null;

-----

public get cardNotPresentTurnover(): string {
  const { cardNotPresentTurnover } = this.location;

  if (isNil(cardNotPresentTurnover)) {
    return "Unknown";
  }

  const { max, min } = cardNotPresentTurnover;
  const isUnknown = isNil(min) || isNil(max);

  if (isUnknown) {
    return "Unknown";
  }

  return `${min}% - ${max}%`;
}
```

Also, maybe cut down on the length of your thingies to make it a little more readable :P

Comment: It works if I do   public get cardNotPresentTurnover(): string {
    return !this.location?.cardNotPresentTurnover?.min &&
      !this.location?.cardNotPresentTurnover?.max
      ? 'Unknown'
      : `${this.location.cardNotPresentTurnover.min}% - ${this.location.cardNotPresentTurnover.max}%`;
  }

Comment: You're right @Tom , I think the checking logic was wrong. I cleaned it up a little and it should now be correct. Still not 100% sure, but the main issue is definitely `0` being used as `false`.

Comment: @M1CH3L1US In his case that with the 0 is not true, because he use strings, it would be the case if it were a number. If you do something like that '0' ? 'true' : 'false', the result will be true and not false, because the string is not empty.

Comment: Silly me, I totally missed that in the original question